# Why won't || work in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shellcheck

```
# Detect Operating System
function dist-check() {
  # shellcheck disable=SC1090
  if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC1091
    source /etc/os-release
    DISTRO=$ID
    # shellcheck disable=SC2034
    DISTRO_VERSION=$VERSION_ID
  fi
}

# Check Operating System
dist-check

# Pre-Checks
function installing-system-requirements() {
  # shellcheck disable=SC2233,SC2050
  if ([ "$DISTRO" == "ubuntu" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "debian" ] || [ "DISTRO" == "raspbian" ]); then
    apt-get update && apt-get install iptables curl coreutils bc jq sed e2fsprogs -y
  fi
  # shellcheck disable=SC2233,SC2050
  if ([ "$DISTRO" == "fedora" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "centos" ] || [ "DISTRO" == "rhel" ]); then
    yum update -y && yum install epel-release iptables curl coreutils bc jq sed e2fsprogs -y
  fi
  if [ "$DISTRO" == "arch" ]; then
    pacman -Syu --noconfirm iptables curl bc jq sed
  fi
}

# Run the function and check for requirements
installing-system-requirements
```

Why wont this run?

I am using `||` to separate the distros but its still not working.

Comment: Which shell are you scripting for? ...also, your 3rd checks are missing `$` on `DISTRO`.

Comment: ... this looks like something that could be more simply written as a `case` statement

Comment: If you haven't been disabling all shellcheck findings, you would be able to detect this. 

Comment: have you run it through `shellcheck`? Are you doing one change at a time, and testing? It so then the bug will be in the last thing that you changed.

Answer (score 3):

Some other notes:

`function installing-system-requirements()` is not standard syntax to define functions. The Bourne/POSIX syntax is `installing-system-requirements() compound-command`, `function installing-system-requirements { ...; }` is the Korn syntax. Combining both like that just works (mostly by accident) in pdksh, zsh and bash (though some shells like busybox sh and yash have added support for that since for compatibility with bash).

`(...)` is to introduce a subshell environment, which in most shells is implemented by forking a child shell process. You'd only use that to sort of isolate a section of code for changes in there not to be persistent. It doesn't make much sense to use them as you do here.

The equality comparison for the `[` utility is `=`, not `==` (though some `[` implementations understand `==` as well as an extension).

Here, you have a number of independent `if` statements. That means that if `$DISTRO` already matched `debian` for instance, you would still try and compare it to `fedora`. To avoid that, you could use `elif` for the subsequence checks:

```
if [ "$DISTRO" = debian ] || [ "$DISTRO" = ubuntu ]; then
  ...
elif [ "$DISTRO" = fedora ] || [ "$DISTRO" = centos ]; then
  ...
fi
```

But to match a string against several values or patterns, using a `case` construct would make it a lot easier:

```
case "$DISTRO" in
  (ubuntu | debian) ...;;
  (ferdora | centos) ...;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Detect Operating System
function dist-check() {
  # shellcheck disable=SC1090
  if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC1091
    source /etc/os-release
    DISTRO=$ID
    # shellcheck disable=SC2034
    DISTRO_VERSION=$VERSION_ID
  fi
}

# Check Operating System
dist-check

# Pre-Checks
function installing-system-requirements() {
  # shellcheck disable=SC2233,SC2050
  if ([ "$DISTRO" == "ubuntu" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "debian" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "raspbian" ]); then
    apt-get update && apt-get install iptables curl coreutils bc jq sed e2fsprogs -y
  fi
  # shellcheck disable=SC2233,SC2050
  if ([ "$DISTRO" == "fedora" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "centos" ] || [ "$DISTRO" == "rhel" ]); then
    yum update -y && yum install epel-release iptables curl coreutils bc jq sed e2fsprogs -y
  fi
  if [ "$DISTRO" == "arch" ]; then
    pacman -Syu --noconfirm iptables curl bc jq sed
  fi
}

# Run the function and check for requirements
installing-system-requirements
```

Was missing `$` from `DISTRO`